# Why python file is called twice?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I call Python file using PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {

    $handle = new upload($_FILES['file']);

    if ($handle->uploaded) {
        //$handle->allowed = array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        $handle->file_max_size = '1000000';
        $handle->process('/uploaded/');

        if ($handle->processed) {
            echo system('/myenv/bin/python3.4 /home/run.py ' . $handle->file_dst_pathname, $retval);
            $handle->clean();

        } else {
            echo 'Error : ' . $handle->error;
        }
    }

}
```

File `run.py` contains following:

```
import sys
import os.path
print("ok")
```

When I run php script in calls python script twice, because I get message "ok" twice in browser.

How to fix it?

If to ad echo before calling script it give me one time number `1` it means that php works one time

```
echo "1";
echo system('/....
```

Comment: From the code shown, it will only run the Python code once. Is the `process` function maybe also running it? Or the `clean` function? Or some other bit of PHP code elsewhere also generating an ok output?

Comment: Or I suspect works print in `Python` and print in PHP, it gives 2 print

Comment: Add some extra echos into the PHP code before and after the system call, to be sure that both oks are coming from that. Try not echoing the result of the system call, and see what effect that has.